# Efficient Blending of Non-Nan-Sparse Transformed Mosaic Images in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm currently working on improving the blending part of the image *mosaic* sample application on VLfeat's homepage. In this final *blending* stage I want to *combine* two non-nan-sparse images, both being the output from two images interpolations using `interp2` with `nan`-flag. Specifically, given two image matrices `A` and `B` and blended matrix `C` all of same dimension `M`-by-`N`, I want for each matrix position (`i`,`j`) in `A` and `B` want to check whehter

- both `A` and `B` have a defined value in `(i,j)` so make `C(i,j)` the average of them or,
- either `A` or `B` have a defined (`~isnan()`) value in `(i,j)` so put that in `C(i,j)` or,
- neither `A` nor `B` have a defined value in `(i,j)` thereby leaving C(i,j) as is

assuming C is initialized to all nan values.

I haven't find a simple nor elegant way of doing this without having to

- *reshape* A and B into *vectors*
- find non-nan vector *indexes* `AI=find(~isnan(A))` and `BI=find(~isnan(B))`
- find *intersection* `II` of `AI` and `BI`
- use `II`, `AI` and `BI` to modify a vector C of same length as `A` and `B` as mentioned in three steps above
- reshape `C` back to `M`-by-`N` to finally get result wanted

I have tried to express the same steps using matrices and matrix indexes without success. Is this the only way of doing this in MATLAB? It seems kind of cumbersome.

Comment: I simplified the tags, I'm feeling that although the tags you chose where related to your needs, the question is a matlab generic one. Please retag if you think I'm wrong.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Are there any tag-use recommendations available online stackoverflow somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something (I do not understand why you need to reshape matrix to vectors, for example).

Anyway, here is a try:

```
% Unconditionnaly compute the average into temp D matrix
D=(A+B)/2;
% Restore A and B values where B and A are NaN
D(isnan(A))=B(isnan(A));
D(isnan(B))=A(isnan(B));
% Only modify C wherever the final result is not NaN
C(~isnan(D))=D(~isnan(D));
```

Comment: Clever. I'll stick with that for now.